# How can I restart a game in Processing?

Tags: java, processing

So I wanted to write a processing game where you try to catch a falling ball with basketball ring. It all goes pretty well until at some point, when you win or lose and press "restart" the game won't restart.
This is my setup() method (only the relevant part of initializing variables):

```java
void setup() {
    game = new Game();
    scr = new SplashScreen();
    gameBackground = new Image();
    background = new DynamicBackground();
    button = new Rect();

    /* Music set */
    intro = new Music();
    lifeMusic = new Music();
    failMusic = new Music();

    /* Ball and ring set */
    ball = new Image();
    ring = new Image();

    /* Life points set */
    life1 = new Image();
    life2 = new Image();
    life3 = new Image();
    life4 = new Image();
    failCount = 3;
    sucCount =0;
    winStr = "YOU WON!";
    gameOverStr = "GAME OVER";
    restartStr = "Resetart";

    flag = true;
    win = new Text();
    gameOver = new Text();
    restart = new Text();

    size(710, 490);

    .....
}
```

and this is my `mousePressed` method:

```java
void mousePressed(){
    if(mouseX>button.x && mouseX <button.x+button.width && mouseY>button.y && mouseY <button.y+button.height){
        loop();
        setup();
    }
}
```

as you see, I tried to do `noLoop()` when the game is over, and than when you press on the button I called "restart" it will `loop()` and `setup()`.

The game get stuck when I press "restart" why?

Answer (score 2):

[`setup()`](https://processing.org/reference/setup_.html) is called by an internal callback. It is not intended to call `setup`. Note in setup the window is initialized (`size(710, 490);`). The call of setup causes the system to hang.

Keep the initialization of the static objects in `setup`, but move the initialization of all the dynamic objects (the "moving" ones) to an `init` function. Call this function in `setup` and `mousePressed`:

```java
void init() {
    game = new Game();
    scr = new SplashScreen();
    gameBackground = new Image();
    background = new DynamicBackground();
    button = new Rect();

    /* Ball and ring set */
    ball = new Image();
    ring = new Image();

    // ...
}
```

```java
void setup() {

    size(710, 490);

    // init static objects

    /* Music set */
    intro = new Music();
    lifeMusic = new Music();
    failMusic = new Music();

    // init dynamic objects
    init();
}
```

```java
void mousePressed(){
    if(mouseX>button.x && mouseX <button.x+button.width && mouseY>button.y && mouseY <button.y+button.height){
        init();
        loop();
    }
}
```

Comment: it still doesnt work... :\ I left the setup method only with size(...,...) and init() like you said but still get stucked

Comment: @NoaIsr Do you call  `noLoop()` somewhere? Do you even have a `draw` function?

Comment: yes ofc , I have a full draw function when I make the game happened. when the game is over, I call noLoop()

Comment: @NoaIsr It is not necessary to recreate all objects. It is sufficient to recreate the objects which are moving or changing. Of course you've to call restart the loop when the mouse is pressed.